# How to open new form in C# with button name?

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm making a little application and i don't know how to open new window of app with parameters of clicked button. 
For example: If i click to hydrogen, i want to open form called prvek, which will display informations about it.

Sorry for my bad English. Here's screenshot of main window:
[Main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PchRD.jpg)

Comment: Is windows form or web app?

Comment: `fromname.Show();` for winforms

Comment: WinForms or WPF?  (Or something else?)  I imagine just about any tutorial on the technology being used will cover *opening a form*, no?

Comment: Jorge: windows form:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a form in Windows Forms simply involves creating an instance of that form and calling `.Show()` on that instance.  For example:

```
var someForm = new SomeForm();
someForm.Show();
```

---

If you want to pass values to that form, you can set them as constructor arguments.  For example, in `SomeForm`:

```
public SomeForm(int someValue)
{
    // do something with someValue
}
```

Then when you create it:

```
var someForm = new SomeForm(aValue);
someForm.Show();
```

---

Or if the values aren't necessarily required, but you happen to have them available at this time, maybe set them as properties.  In `SomeForm`:

```
public int SomeValue { get; set; }
```

Then when you create it:

```
var someForm = new SomeForm();
someForm.SomeValue = aValue;
someForm.Show();
```

or:

```
var someForm = new SomeForm { SomeValue = aValue };
someForm.Show();
```

---

Where you get your values, of course, is up to you.  I'm not sure what you mean by "parameters of the clicked button".  But in the click event there should be an `object sender` which is a reference to the UI element that triggered the event.

So, for example, if you want a property from the `Button` that was clicked, you can cast `sender` to `Button` and read its information.  Something like this:

```
var buttonText = ((Button)sender).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to give your second form, prvek, a property that you can set from your first.  For example:

```
public string Element { get; private set; };
```

Then, in your button_onClick method you should be able to do the following:

```
ElementForm myForm = new ElementForm(); //Whatever the class name is of your second form
myForm.Element = ((Button)this).Name; //Get the name of the button
myForm.Show();
```

In your second form's constructor or initializer method, you'll want to set the title of the form:

```
public ElementForm()
{
    InitializeComponent()
    this.Text = Element;
}
```

Comment: is this good? I'm starting with c# `prvekform = new prvek(); //Whatever the class name is of your second form
            prvekform.Element = ((Button)this).Name; //Get the name of the button
            prvekform.Show();`

Comment: That's correct.  The only thing remaining is to set the form's text to the value of Element in it's constructor.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/DdCedy3arw6tn

Comment: My bad, I did forget a piece there.  myForm needs to be a variable.  In your case, you'll want to write out `prvek myForm = new prvek();`